# Magento 2 - Field Depedency does not hides label of field when field has "after_element_html" in its $config?

Tags: magento-2.0.4

As shown in this two [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/436rS.jpg), after selecting the HIDE option from the select, the field OP does not hide entirely. I noticed that it only happens when the field OP does have a "after_element_html" in its $config.

This is an expected behaivior?

Answer (score 0):

I should saw it early...

I was using `after_element_html` to put a help message, when i should be using the note option when defining the field.

Nonetheless, if using `after_element_html` should hide the field entirely